# Is it possible to post a review using Yelp API?

Tags: yelp

I am working with yelp api, I am able to retrieve the product reviews with the help of the api.

However, is it also possible to post a review using Yelp API?

I need to post a review for a product from my own php script.

Comment: how are you retrieving the reviews?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the Yelp API is currently read-only.